# How to select from or store result of sp_describe_first_result_set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, metadata, azure-synapse

When we call the stored procedure `sp_describe_first_result_set` in SQL server, it displays to us rows that describe the contents of what the query that was passed in would return.

Is it possible to operate on this result? For example, select columns from it, store in a variable, etc. - it seems that the stored procedure itself is just returning a code as per usual (0, or 1), but no output, so is my only option to recreate it? What is it doing internally to produce its results?

For example:

```sql
EXEC  @result = sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql= N'SELECT * FROM MyTable'
PRINT('status code only, not the schema  :( :( :( = ' + @result)
```

This is within the Serverless SQL Pool part of Azure Synapse Analytics, so `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` is not supported.

Comment: Does [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) help?

Comment: This [article](https://www.sqlmovers.com/using-a-temporary-table-to-handle-sp_describe_first_result_set/) presents an example of how to create a TEMP table with the proper schema which will allow you to `INSERT` the result set from a call to `sp_describe_first_result_set`.  The article also goes further and uses the result set for additional processing.

Comment: That does it, and works within Serverless SQL Pool in Azure Synapse, since thankfully it supports temp tables... thanks @DavidTansey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work in Synapse SQL team.

You can use code below to populate temp table #t with result set of sp_describe_first_result_set. Idea is to create temp table with the same columns as SP returns and then use INSERT INTO

```
CREATE TABLE #t (
    is_hidden bit NOT NULL, 
    column_ordinal int NOT NULL, 
    name sysname NULL, 
    is_nullable bit NOT NULL, 
    system_type_id int NOT NULL, 
    system_type_name nvarchar(256) NULL, 
    max_length smallint NOT NULL, 
    precision tinyint NOT NULL, 
    scale tinyint NOT NULL, 
    collation_name sysname NULL, 
    user_type_id int NULL, 
    user_type_database sysname NULL, 
    user_type_schema sysname NULL, 
    user_type_name sysname NULL, 
    assembly_qualified_type_name nvarchar(4000), 
    xml_collection_id int NULL, 
    xml_collection_database sysname NULL, 
    xml_collection_schema sysname NULL, 
    xml_collection_name sysname NULL, 
    is_xml_document bit NOT NULL, 
    is_case_sensitive bit NOT NULL, 
    is_fixed_length_clr_type bit NOT NULL, 
    source_server nvarchar(128), 
    source_database nvarchar(128), 
    source_schema nvarchar(128), 
    source_table nvarchar(128), 
    source_column nvarchar(128), 
    is_identity_column bit NULL, 
    is_part_of_unique_key bit NULL, 
    is_updateable bit NULL, 
    is_computed_column bit NULL, 
    is_sparse_column_set bit NULL, 
    ordinal_in_order_by_list smallint NULL, 
    order_by_list_length smallint NULL, 
    order_by_is_descending smallint NULL, 
    tds_type_id int NOT NULL, 
    tds_length int NOT NULL, 
    tds_collation_id int NULL, 
    tds_collation_sort_id tinyint NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO #t EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK ''https://pandemicdatalake.blob.core.windows.net/public/curated/covid-19/ecdc_cases/latest/ecdc_cases.csv'',
        FORMAT = ''CSV'',
        PARSER_VERSION = ''2.0'') as [r]'

SELECT * FROM #t
```

Comment: Thanks Filip - as you are on the team, may I trouble you to please take a look at this one as well if you would be so kind? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67112304/azure-synapse-how-to-cross-apply-json-path