# Azure Synapse how to CROSS APPLY JSON PATH

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I'd like to dynamically pull rows of data based on a few fields from another table and summarize it as JSON when joining it in as a single row.

Here's a small example to illustrate.

**[Test].[dbo].[tableA]**

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | i |
| 2 | ii |
| 3 | iii |

**[Test].[dbo].[tableB]**

| A_id | B_Col1 | B_Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | b11 | b12 |
| 1 | b111 | b112 |
| 2 | b21 | b22 |
| 2 | b22 | b222 |

**Query:**

```sql
      SELECT * FROM [Test].[dbo].[tableA] as A
        CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT (
              SELECT * FROM [Test].[dbo].[tableB] as B
              WHERE B.A_id = A.Col1
              FOR JSON PATH
          ) as B_JSON
      ) as CA
```

**Result** (as expected in SQL Server)

| Col1 | Col2 | B_JSON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | i | [{"A_id":1,"B_Col1":"b11","B_Col2":"b12"},{"A_id":1,"B_Col1":"b111","B_Col2":"b112"}] |
| 2 | ii | [{"A_id":2,"B_Col1":"b21","B_Col2":"b22"},{"A_id":2,"B_Col1":"b22","B_Col2":"b222"}] |
| 3 | iii | NULL |

**Result in Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pool**:

> The query references an object that is not supported in distributed
> processing mode.

Trouble is, it doesn't like the SELECT around the FOR JSON result, but we need that to assign a column name such that the Cross Apply works.

Question is thus; what is the best way to achieve this within this context?

Comment: What happens if you try the inner query by itself

Comment: To clarify, Statements like the inner-most select in example above to produce JSON works @Charlieface , but to wrap it another SELECT to give it a column name fails with the error cited above

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/241906/using-json-auto-in-azure-synapse-analytics-sql-poo.html

Comment: @charlieface that link must be outdated, as I said above the JSON result is getting created just fine within azure synapse serverless SQL pool, only the outer select on it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot test this in your environment, so this might not work...
You can try one of these:

```
DECLARE @tblA TABLE(Col1 INT, Col2 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tblA(Col1,Col2) VALUES
 (1,'i')
,(2,'ii')
,(3,'iii');

DECLARE @tblB TABLE(A_id INT,B_Col1 VARCHAR(10),B_Col2 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tblB(A_id,B_Col1,B_Col2) VALUES
 (1,'b11','b12')
,(1,'b111','b112')
,(2,'b21','b22')
,(2,'b22','b222');
```

--Pass the column's name behind the CA's name (avoids the nested SELECT)

```
  SELECT * FROM @tblA as A
    CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT * FROM @tblB as B
          WHERE B.A_id = A.Col1
          FOR JSON PATH
      ) CA(B_JSON);
```

--Avoid the CA totally by using a scalar sub-select

```
  SELECT A.Col1
        ,A.Col2
        ,(
          SELECT * FROM @tblB as B
          WHERE B.A_id = A.Col1
          FOR JSON PATH
         ) AS B_JSON
  FROM @tblA as A;
```

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo, really appreciate the attempt, great suggestions. Unfortunately, both result in same error in Synapse SQL on-demand ("The query references an object that is not supported in distributed processing mode"). Would love to understand why - think this needs to go to the product team to find that out.

Comment: Looks liek they have now implemented this in Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pools and it works as expected.